How to remove the default landing page of CapRover
I have CapRover set up on a vps with a domain (*.domain.com) pointing to it. After following there docs, everything works fine but there is one undesired behaviour that I can’t disable. By default CapRover sets up a landing page for every subdomain of (*.domain.com);
so if I create an app named “abc” it will be served at abc.domain.com which is as expected, but for every other subdomain (ie: any.domain.com) it serves a default landing page instead of just a regular undefined page, which one would expect for an undefined subdomain. I can't find any mention on how to diable this in the docs, so if anyone knows how to do so it would help me a lot.
